# Trying to generate an email alert as soon as error string is encountered in tailing log file via cron job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I need to generate an email alert when this script reads an error string from a tailing log file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script is starting"
logLocation="/apps/ca/share/scripts/moveTos3.log"
echo $logLocation
Email_Dest="abc@abc.com"
echo $Email_Dest
tail -f $logLocation|while read line;do
echo $line
if [ `echo $line|grep error` -ne 0 ];
then
 mail -s "test3" $Email_Dest < echo $line;
fi
done
```

As of now I am not able to get the email. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `< echo $line;` with `<<< "$line"`.

Comment: replace `\`echo $line |grep error\` -ne 0\`` with `\`grep -q error "$line"\``

Comment: no didn't work my log file looks like below

Comment: thanks but didn't work my log file looks like below
"Welcome to sftp> put /some/file/dir/sample_13_26_02.csv
Uploading /some/file/dir/sample_07_27_13_26_02.csv 
sftp> put /some/file/dir/sample_07_27_13_26_02.tag
sftp> quit
Sat Nov 16 18:10:18 UTC 2019 Deleting file /some/file/dir/07_27_13_26_02.csv
Sat Nov 16 18:10:18 UTC 2019 Deleting file /some/file/dir/_07_27_13_26_02.tag"

and tailing every 5min as the cron schedule, need to catch grep the error string when this log file start tailing/updating every 5min.

Comment: You refer to 2 jobs - the FTP, and the monitor. Which one is executing as a recurring 5 minute cron ?

Comment: *"I am not able to get the email"* is not very useful. You should provide details of the failure. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted here will never send an email.

This `if` clause:

```
if [ `echo $line|grep error` -ne 0 ];
then
 mail -s "test3" $Email_Dest < echo $line;
fi
```

doesn't work the way you think it is.

#### Syntax of `if`

In the unix shell, the syntax for `if` is:

```
if command-list-1; then
    some-commands;
elif command-list-2; then
    some-commands;
elif command-list-3; then
    some-commands;
...
else
    some-commands;
fi
```

So 2 things to notice here:

1. `if` doesn't take conditions, it takes command lists.
2. No mention of `[ ... ]`.

In your case, what you want as command-list-1 is:

```
! echo $line | grep error
```

Namely:

```
if ! $line | grep error;
then
 mail -s "test3" $Email_Dest < echo $line;
fi
```

At this point you might have some questions:

1. Don't I need to check against 0?
2. Why `!` and what is it?
3. So what's the deal with the square brackets?
4. So what does the original code do? Why does it never send an email?

#### Don't I need to check against 0?

`if` (and other shell conditionals e.g. `while`) works by running the command list, and check what it returned.

The Unix convention, on which the shell relies, is that a successful execution returns 0, and a failed execution returns anything else. So if the command list returns 0, the shell executes the `then` clause, and otherwise it goes to the `else` or the next `elif` clause.

The command list I spelled out above will return 0 if `grep error` failed.

Bonus tip: Unix has 2 useful programs, `/bin/true` and `/bin/false`, which allow you to do things like `if true; then ...; fi`. That is not very useful, until you realize you can set variables to use this:

```
if [ $(uname -s) = Linux ]; then
    USE_GNU=true
else
    USE_GNU=false
fi
...
if $USE_GNU; then
    ...
fi
```

#### Why `!` and what is it?

The return value of a command list is the return value of the last command in the list.

In the example here there's only one command, `! echo $line | grep error`.

When a command is a pipeline, the return value is the return value of the last command in the pipe, and `grep` returns 0 if it found something and 1 if it didn't.

But we need the opposite condition, so we prepend `!` to the pipeline, which inverts the return value of a pipe, so if `grep` returned 0, it will return 1, thus causing `if` to skip the `then` clause.

#### So what's the deal with the square brackets?

In the majority of cases you want to test a simple condition, e.g. if a file exists or if the variable `X` is greater than 10. Since the shell only accepts programs, there's a program `/usr/bin/test` that does these:

- `test -f /my/file` will return 0 if the file exists and 1 if it doesn't.
- `test $X -gt 10` will return 0 if the value of `X` is greater than 10 and 1 if it isn't.

You'd use it as follows:

```
if test $X -gt 10; then
    ...
fi
```

But people wanted to make the shell pretty. So they created a program, `/usr/bin/[` (yes!), which has the following syntax: `[ <expression> ]`, which literally executes `test <expression>`.

This allows you to rewrite `if test $X -gt 10; then ...; fi` as `if [ $X -gt 10 ]; then ...; fi`.

#### So what does the original code do? Why does it never send an email?

Now you can see that the original code first executes `echo $line|grep error`, which either prints a line with the word "error" in it, or prints nothing. It then captures this output, and passes it as one of the arguments to `[`.

If you look at the man page for `[` (!!!) you'll see that the syntax `[ <text> -ne <number> ]` or `[ -ne <number> ]` is not valid, and if you run them, you'll see that `[` prints something like "syntax error" and returns 2.

Because `[` always returns 2 in the original code, `if` sees a non-zero and skips the `then` clause.